# Extracting 2 elements from ul using cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

Id like to extract 2 elements from each `li` inside this unordered list:

```
<ul class="cookieAlertList padTop10">

      <li>

       <img src="images/cookieradar/iconHot.gif" />
       <div class="cookieAlertDesc">
       <a href="/P.aspx?p=16aa6d76104">
        Peanut Butter Chocolate Chunk
       </a>
       <br />
       <small>44 mins ago</small>
       </div>

      </li>

      <li>

       <img src="images/cookieradar/iconHot.gif" />
       <div class="cookieAlertDesc">
       <a href="/P.aspx?p=15936a56102">
        Oatmeal Wheatgerm Chocolate Chip
       </a>
       <br />
       <small>48 mins ago</small>
       </div>

      </li>

     </ul>
```

For each of those list items, id like to extract the cookie name (contained in the  element) and the time, contained in the  element.

I was able to extract the 2 list items using:

`var li = $('.cookieAlertList').find('li');`

but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

// some HTTP Requests to scrape the page content.. 

var $ = cheerio.load(html);

var result = [];

$('ul.cookieAlertList li').each(function(el) {
    var $div = $(el).find('div.cookieAlertDesc');
    var obj = {
        cookieName: $div.find('a').text(),
        time: $div.find('small').text()
    };
    result.push(obj);
});

console.log('result', result); // JSON.stringify(result, null, 3);
```

Comment: Cool, this prints out the correct amount of cookie objects, but the cookieName and time fields are blank. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Ah, I think the function in .each() takes 2 parameters, i and el. Seems to be working now.

Comment: i think its not really important. you may pass it if you need it.

Comment: are you making http requests to scrape the page content?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37438168/6243352), using more precise selectors, spread syntax, `map` and `.trim()`:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<HTML as above>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = [...$(".cookieAlertList li")].map(e => ({
  name: $(e).find(".cookieAlertDesc a").text().trim(),
  time: $(e).find(".cookieAlertDesc small").text().trim(),
}));
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```js
[
  { name: 'Peanut Butter Chocolate Chunk', time: '44 mins ago' },
  { name: 'Oatmeal Wheatgerm Chocolate Chip', time: '48 mins ago' }
]
```