# Get text from li using cheerio

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I want to get an JSON-output using Cheerio in nodejs that has the following layout:

```
[
    {
        teamName: 'M08-ARG',
        time: '16:00 - 17:00',
        veld: 1CD
    }
    ...
    {
        teamName: 'J08-SPA',
        time: '16:00 - 17:00',
        veld: 1A
    }
]
```

(part of) the html of my website is:

```
<div class="matches_container">
    <section class="column matches screen5">
        <ul class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li class="bg-title-list">
                <h3 class="tite-list">Meisjes</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    M08-ARG
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1CD
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    M08-IND
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1B
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    MO8-BEL
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1CD
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    
    <section class="column matches screen5">
        <ul class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
            <li class="bg-title-list"></li>
                <h3 class="tite-list">Jongens</h3>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    J08-ARG
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1A
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    J08-BEL
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1A
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="position-list">
                <div class="teamName">
                    J08-SPA
                </div>
                <time>
                    16:00 - 17:00
                </time>
                <div class="text">
                    <span class="img">&nbsp;</span>Veld 1A
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```

What I have so far:

```js
console.log("1"); //debug
var result = [];
$("#Left > div > section:nth-child(1) > ul").each(function (el) {
  console.log("2"); //debug
  var $li = $(el).find("li");
  var obj = {
    teamName: $li.find("div.teamName").text(),
    time: $li.find("time").text(),
    veld: $li.find("div.text > span").text(),
  };
  console.log(obj);
  result.push(obj);
});
console.log(result);
```

I do get logged in the console a '1'. So that far everything is working. However, I should see some numbers 2 as well but there aren't any. I think I go wrong with the selectors. If I use Chrome to inspect the element for eg. teamName, it comes up with `#Left > div > section:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div.teamName`, time comes up with `#Left > div > section:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > time` and veld comes up with `#Left > div > section:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > div.text > span`

Console output:
`Opening the browser...... 1 []`

I have used the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423893/extracting-2-elements-from-ul-using-cheerio) question as a reference for my code since the structure looked the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to loop over the `<li>` elements, not the `<ul>` elements.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<HTML as above>`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = [...$(".matches_container .position-list")].map(e => ({
  teamName: $(e).find(".teamName").text().trim(),
  time: $(e).find("time").text().trim(),
  veld: $(e).find(".text").text().trim().split(/ +/).pop(),
}));
console.log(result);
```

If you want to maintain the `<ul>` groupings in your output, add an extra loop/map over the `<ul>` elements and loop over `<li>`s in an inner loop:

```js
const result = [...$(".matches_container .jcarousel-skin-tango")].map(e =>
  [...$(e).find(".position-list")].map(e => ({
    teamName: $(e).find(".teamName").text().trim(),
    time: $(e).find("time").text().trim(),
    veld: $(e).find(".text").text().trim().split(/ +/).pop(),
  }))
);
```

I don't see `#Left` in your shared markup but I assume that's in the actual HTML.

If this fails on the live site, it's probably because JS is injecting the elements dynamically, you're being blocked as a bot, or there's a naming clash on some of these selectors. In that case, feel free to share your URL and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you! You're right about the `#left` part. It is indeed part of the whole html. I just noticed as I was reviewing my question. Sorry I cut it to short. There might be a possibility of being blocked. I will try and find out.

Comment: Works like a charm! If possible, could you explain the approach so I can learn from it?

Comment: Glad to hear! What part is confusing? `map` is just a shorthand for creating an array and pushing onto it--the return values are collected in a new array automatically. Otherwise, the selector switch from looping over `<ul>`s to looping over `<li>`s is the key.